# Confidence intervals for variable importance in conditional random forests

Tags: r, random-forest, confidence-interval

I am running conditional random forests in r with factor response variables and numeric input variables. I would like to get some type measure that will give an indication of confidence intervals for the variable importance measures. Is there a function that provides a measure of this type? I feel I have done a fairly exhaustive search and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you should check out the rfPermute package:

> *Estimate significance of importance metrics for a Random Forest model by permuting the response variable. Produces null distribution of
>   importance metrics for each predictor variable and p-value of
>   observed*

I also recommend you to read the Strobl article ["Bias in random forest variable importance measures: Illustrations, sources and a solution"](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/8/25)

Comment: Thank you for this. It looks very helpful. Although it does appear to only be for random forest objects and not conditional random forests (from party package). I have had a quick play with it and am getting a lot of the same p values, but will continue running some different models to see how I go. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: I have taken a glimpse at the source code, it should be possible with some modifications to support cforest also. Have not seen any published on these p-values though. Try mail the maintainer, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rfPermute/index.html